# What to do with pure visualization questions?

Tags: discussion

We have the first of its kind, [How to draw a threshold line](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/459/good-line-color-for-threshold-line-in-a-time-series-graph). Especially this question fits best for User Interface (which is still on Area51), but it shows the problem.

Comment: True. That was my question, and there's no statistical analysis component to it. I associate "data visualization" more strongly with "statistical analysis" than I do with "user interface", which to me is software/web GUI, navigation, etc. This seems to fall in both/neither topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that question was perfectly fine.  Although the line in question wasn't data-derived, the issue was clearly how that line should be drawn in order to help the plot tell the right story *about the visualized data*.

Comment: No one complains, so we will be also a visualization Q&A... Too bad for http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11508/infographics-and-data-visualization ;-)