# Is it appropriate to ask for suggestions/solicit ideas on data visualizations?

Tags: discussion

I have a site where I am placing heavy emphasis on UX and data visualization, as I have large sets of data that I'm looking to convey in a meaningful, easy-to-consume way.

That said, I feel it falls under the general topic of data visualization, which is indicated as an appropriate question for the site.

Of course, the community might have other ideas so I wanted to check here first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's okay with us, I think.  See: [What to do with pure visualization questions?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109/what-to-do-with-pure-visualization-questions)